# TEXT(5,"0") does not equal 5 formatted as text

Tags: excel

There are several ways to convert numbers to text in excel:

- `TEXT(5, "0")`
- `="5"`
- `=5&""`
- Right-clicking cell > Format Cells... > Text

However, the last of these is somehow different from the first three. Any comparisons made between a number converted using the first three and the fourth will come back FALSE when using the same number.

I tried doing a lookup where I extracted a number from a string and looked for it in a column of numbers that I had converted to Text using Format Cells..., and it didn't find the number. They are different data types somehow? Why is this occurring?

Comment: The last one does **NOT** change the data type. You can prove this to yourself by applying the formula `ISNUMBER(cell_ref)` to that cell. If you type the numeral `5` into a text-formatted cell, it will be accepted as text. But changing the data type of a cell formatted as `General` which contains a numeric value will not change the data type. (The reverse is also true, but that is a different question).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Ah thanks, that makes sense. So the takeaway is formatting and data types in excel are (very) different things that are sometimes confused for one another

Comment: @RonRosenfeld. Do you mean `But changing the Number formatting of a cell`?

Comment: @Blackcat Yes. I mis-typed